# React-Native Import class issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am importing chatscreen.js for createStackNavigator in app.js. I have `var socket = socketio.getSocket();` code in chatscreen.js , When import code run in app.js , this getSocket(); running.

I would like to run socketio.socketConnect(); before import chatscreen.js in app.js but I couldn't create this logic

App.js

```
import ChatScreen from './components/ChatScreen/ChatScreen';
import socketio from './components/Classes/socketio';
import SplashScreen from './components/SplashScreen/SplashScreen';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props); 
}
}
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
     Splash:{screen: SplashScreen},
     Chat:{screen: ChatScreen},
}
```

ChatScreen.js

```
import socketio from '../Classes/socketio';
var socket = socketio.getSocket();

class ChatScreen extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);  
}
}
```

socketio.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

class socketio extends Component{


    static socketConnect(domain){
                socket = io("http://"+domainToken,{jsonp:false})
    }

    static getSocket(){
        if (!socket) {
            throw new Error("Must call socketConnect() before getSocket()");
        }
        return socket;
    }
}

export default socketio;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your socketio.js, you have made it a class component instead you should make it a functional component like this:

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;


    function socketConnect(domain){
                socket = io("http://"+domainToken,{jsonp:false})
    }

    function getSocket(){
        if (!socket) {
            throw new Error("Must call socketConnect() before getSocket()");
        }
        return socket;
    }

module.exports = {
socketConnect,
getSocket
}
```

then you can import it like this:

```
import socketio from '../Classes/socketio';
var socket = socketio.getSocket();
class ChatScreen extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);  
}

componentDidMount(){
  socketio.socketConnect(domain)
}
}
```

Comment: Still same error Must call socketConnect() before getSocket()

Comment: are you calling socketConnect() before getSocket()?

Comment: firstly I am importing chatscreen.js in app.js , this time getsocket running. But I am taking  my domain from asyncstorage in app.js screen. I sould to run connectSocket before import chatscreen.js in app.js

Comment: so you want to access getsocket from two different places and get the same object?

Comment: yes, But firstly i should to run AsyncStorage.getItem('domain').then((domain) => {socketio.socketConnec(domain)}); before import ChatScreen from './components/ChatScreen/ChatScreen'; in app.js. Because if i import chatscreen.js in app.js firstly run getSocket in chatScreen.js

Comment: So the problem is that you need to maintain a global state where you can update global variables like socket, you can do this by using redux, Jumpsuit or Mobx, all of these are good solutions but I have used Redux-Sagas with Redux Persist to maintain a global state.

Comment: Did you get the solution or answer?